# Specify the channel (or frequency) for Wi-Fi scan in Android

Tags: android, wifi, frequency

I understand that do a Wi-Fi scan in Android is pretty simple. You get a `WiFiManager`, register a `BroadcastReceiver` and invoke `WiFiManager.startScan()`. Then you just need to **wait**.

The problem is I don't want to wait that long. To do this, instead of scanning all the channel, I would like to scan only a few ones (says `channel 1, 6, 11`). Yet I can't find any API to set the channel to scan. So can any one provide me some tips or hints on how to do this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @VarunJain. No, it seems impossible to do this

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I just checked class WiFiManager but it seems as if there is no such possibility.